# Light bending in a gravitational field and observer independence of events

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, geodesics, thought-experiment

My question pertains to the thought experiment reasoning why light must bend in a gravitational field:

An observer in an elevator in free-fall in a gravitational field is (by the equivalence principle) in an inertial reference frame (assuming the elevator is sufficiently small). Hence, if a beam of photons is fired from a "photon gun" parallel to the floor from one side of the elevator to the other, it will propagate in a straight line hitting a detector fixed to the opposite wall (at the same height as the photon gun). 
**An observer outside the elevator, at rest in the gravitational field, must agree that the photon beam was fired from the "photon gun" from one side of the wall and subsequently "hit" the detector at the same height on the opposite wall, since the two events are observer independent.** Consequently, according to the observer at rest in the gravitational field, the photon beam must follow a curved trajectory.

It is this last bit of reasoning, that I've highlighted in bold for emphasis, that I'm not quite sure how to argue correctly why it must be true?!

It makes sense that both observers should observe the photon beam to "hit" the detector at a specific height on the wall (the alternative of one doing so and the other not seems absurd), but what is the rigorous reasoning behind it?  Is it that *physics* should be *observer independent*, i.e. the occurrence of a given physical phenomenon, such as a photon "hitting" a detector on a wall, should not depend on the frame of reference that it is observed in, it will be observed to occur in all frames of reference (although each observer will assign different space-time coordinates to the event they will all agree that the photon "hit" the detector)?!

Comment: Observer independence is precisely the correct reasoning here; the absence of this principle would, as you say, be logically absurd. We usually take observer independence as a basic assumption in relativity, so I'm not sure that there's any sort of reasoning beyond what you already said.

Comment: @probably_someone OK cool. Is there a correct terminology to use here though (as *event* seems to be exclusively reserved for space-time location)?! Did one simply say that physics is observer independent?!

Comment: I would not object to such a description, and I suspect that your phrasing is the one commonly used in most textbooks (it certainly was in mine).

Comment: @probably_someone Ah ok, that's good to know. Do you know of any text books that discuss this explicitly (in reasonable detail?)

Comment: The one I used had the language directly in the title: *Six Ideas That Shaped Physics, Unit R: The Laws of Physics are Frame-Independent*, by Thomas Moore. This book only covers special relativity, but if you're interested in general relativity, the book *Gravitation*, by Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler, is a good start.

Comment: @probably_someone Thanks for the suggestions, I'll check them out!